# C# Json generic adding

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to add some data into a Json file like this but I have some error :

```
using System.Text.Json;

void addToJson(int myData)
{
   var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<scoreList>(File.ReadAllText("scoreData.json"));

   data.scores.Add(myData);

   var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<scoreList>(data);
   File.WriteAllText("scoreData.json", jsonString);
}
```

I think my code is good, I just have an error at : data.scores.Add(myData);

And here's my class :

```
class scoreTest
    {
        public int score { get; set; }
    }

class scoreList
    {
        public List<scoreTest> scores { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing related to JSON, you should add the proper value to the list

```cs
void addToJson(int myData)
{
    //...
    data.scores.Add(new scoreTest { score = myData });
    //...
}
```

`scores` has `List<scoreTest>` type, you can't simply add `int` value to the list, you should create a `scoreTest` instance first with `score` value set to `myData`

Answer (score 0):

To handle nested class deserialization/serialization use:

```
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All    
    };
```

Try this:

```
void addToJson(int myData)
{
    var settings =  new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All    
    }; 
    var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<scoreList>(File.ReadAllText("scoreData.json"), settings);

    data.scores.Add(myData);

    var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<scoreList>(data, settings);
    File.WriteAllText("scoreData.json", jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is OK, if all member's type are primitive, but if not.
You may need to constructor for a member.
This will helpful to avoid nullreference exception while deserialize.

```
class scoreList { 
    public List<scoreTest> scores { get; set; } 

    //We need default constructor for initialize class member.
    public scoreList(){
        this.scores = new List<scoreTest>();
    }
}
```